# Confused about Python set notation

Tags: python

I keep getting "IndexError: list assignment index out of range." I'm still trying to get the hang of Python. Why do I get an index error when running the program. Is there a better way to go about this? This is just a chunk out of my code.

```
T=a=h=FA=[]

i=1

T[i]=10*(.0001)
a[i]=-1
h[i]=(4)/2
FA[i]=function(-1)
```

I just want to have the sets equal the values at `i=1`.

Comment: List indices start from 0, not 1.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It still will throw an error.

Comment: I think you are treating a list as if it were another data structure, for instance a PHP array (which is a strange container for a number of reasons).  If you want your list to be a set of key-value pairs, whether the keys are integers as you have here or not, then you may wish to use dictionaries instead of lists.  If, on the other hand, the indexes you are using have no particular significance, and you just want an ordered collection, then lists are the container for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your list is empty, hence there is no element 1 to replace. Also, they're all bound to the same list. You don't want that.

```
T=[]
a=[]
h=[]
FA=[]

T.append(10*(.0001))
a.append(-1)
h.append((4)/2)
FA.append(function(-1))
```

Comment: but append just adds the number to the end of the list correct?

Comment: There is nowhere else for an object to go on an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

Use method append or insert. Example:

```
T.append(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only *set* a position which is already present.

You can either

- preallocate your list with the expected number of `0`s in order to overwrite the values afterwards

or

- just append the values to your lists.

BTW:

1. This one

   ```
   T=a=h=FA=[]
   ```

   produces *one* list and makes it accessible via several variables. If you change it via one, the change is visible via the others, too. Better do

   ```
   T = []; a = []; h = []; FA = []
   ```

   or

   ```
   T, a, h, FA = [], [], [], []
   ```

   in order to create four distinct lists (not sets).
2. Indexing is `0`-based, so you wold start with `i = 0` and only then advance to the next values.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand concept of "immutable" and "mutable" objects in python.
Immutable object is an object when any operation on an object creates a new copy of the object and then performs operation on newly created object. For eg,

```
 a = "hello world"
 b = a
 a = "new world"
 print b
 "hello world"
 print a
 "new world"
```

Python immutable objects are str, int, float, tuple

Mutable object on the other hand does not create a new copy of the object and does operation on the same object, Taking the same example as above with a and b as list

```
a = []
b = a
a.append('hi')
print a
['hi']
print b
['hi']
```

both a and b are same copies of the object.
Python lists, sets are Mutable objects.

So in this case it should be `T = []; a = []; h = []; FA = []` for separate lists.

And python list have 'on demand' memory block allocation, so just declaring `a = []` does not create any memory block for this list and thus when you assign a value to an element in the list (eg. `a[1]`) it throws exception. 
`list.append` is the way to go here as you don't have to worry about the list memory allocation problem